# IBM Speech To Text - Get alternative with highest confidence and keyword found as first result

Tags: websphere, speech-to-text, ibm-speech-to-text

I'm using [IBM Speech to Text](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text). The results are OK, but I'm wondering why they are not sorted by highest confidence first. Is there a parameter returning this sorted, so that I could just pick the first alternative? Best would be to only return a result if also the passed keyword is also found.

There is a `max_alternatives` parameter defaulting to 1, but also when specifying this explicitly, more than one alternative is returned.

I'm currently sorting the response manually and I need no code sample for accomplishing this.

JSON example:

```json
   "result": {
        "result_index": 0,
        "results": [
            {
                "final": true,
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "transcript": "l\u00f6schen es tut echte betroffen ",
                        "confidence": 0.71
                    }
                ],
                "keywords_result": {}
            },
            {
                "final": true,
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "transcript": "sie sp\u00fcren dass eine \u00e4ra zu ende ",
                        "confidence": 0.91
                    }
                ],
                "keywords_result": {}
            },
            {
                "final": true,
                "alternatives": [
                    {
                        "transcript": "auto fahre eins zwei drei vier ",
                        "confidence": 0.95
                    }
                ],
                "keywords_result": {
                    "auto": [
                        {
                            "start_time": 6.31,
                            "end_time": 7.19,
                            "confidence": 0.99,
                            "normalized_text": "auto"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the `end_of_phrase_silence_time`. When a default 0.8 silence period is detected, the speech is split into an additional phrase. So what I have seen is not a different recognition result, but an existing phrase in the audio recording mentioned before. See the parameter [end_of_phrase_silence_time](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-parsing#silence-time)